# How to Detect That WP is Using Mod Rewrite or $_GET variables?

Tags: url-rewriting

I am trying to get WP is using Mod_Write or $_GET for URLs,
Because by it, I can generate my own links like:

```
mysite.com/val1/val2
```

or in a conventional way;

```
mysite.com/?var1=val1&var2=val2
```

$_GET or rewrite, how to detect that which way WP is currently using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for the `permalink_structure` option value. If this value is an empty string, WP is using the default permalink structure (`/?var1=val1&var2=val2`), otherwise WP will be using the pretty permalink structure (`/val1/val2`):

```
if ('' != get_option('permalink_structure')) {
    // pretty permalink '/val1/val2'
    ...
} else {
    // default permalink '/?var1=val1&var2=val2' 
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ahmad, this is very simple and what I am looking for